# How to save Timestamp type value in MongoDb | Java

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, bson

From Java driver, I want to save a document that looks like below json in MongoDb

```
{ "ts" : Timestamp(1421006159, 4)}
```

Options I tried.

**Option 1:**
Map doc= new HashMap(1);

```
doc.put("ts", new BSONTimeStamp());
```

It results in the below not required format

```
{"ts" : {
        "_inc" : 0,
        "_class" : "org.bson.types.BSONTimestamp"
    }}
```

**Option 2:**

```
doc.put("ts",new Timestamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

it results in :

```
{"ts" : ISODate("2015-01-12T05:36:43.343Z")}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I used the following with the default mongodb-java-driver (no spring data).

```
DBObject doc= new BasicDBObject();
doc.put("ts", new BSONTimeStamp(1421006159, 4));
```

And the MongoDB result for a find is:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("54b396da7fe45ee2d6c5e03a"), "ts" : Timestamp(1421006159, 4) }
```

So the Serialisation of `BSONTimeStamp` to the classname and the Class attributes an their values depends on the spring-data-mongodb serializer. You should use the default java-mongodb-driver or use Java `Date` and the `ISODate` Format in MongoDB.

Or Maybe you could extend the spring-data-mongodb serializer and Write your own serializer and deserializer for the Class `BSONTimeStamp`  to use the MongoDB Timestamp type.

Comment: You are absolutely right. I tried the same as well and it works with plain mongodb-java-driver. But not with Spring. I also tried with overriding the mongoconverter to avoid _class key but still it doesn't work. Might be a bug in Spring.

Answer (score 4):

From MongoDB they recommend storing a Date since BSON Timestamp is for internal use:

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/bson-types/#timestamps

The difference is that Date has more representation range since is a 64-bit integer that represents the number of milliseconds since Unix epoch.

In BSON Timestamp only 32 bits have this purpose; the other 32 bits are an incremental ordinal integer within a second to assure uniqueness of the value. I suppose this is the reason why they use Timestamp in oplog.

If you don't mind uniqueness I recommend to use a Date (aka ISODate), so option 2 or option 3:

```
doc.put("ts", new Date());
```

Comment: Is this from the Java Default Lib ? "new Date()"?

Comment: Yes, Date from java.util.Date;